# C# Transactionscope multiple connections

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactionscope

I'm trying to execute a query to multiple databases by using a `TransactionScope`.

Here is my code; I want to execute the query on two different SQL Server databases, but in my code, while the query on the first connection executes without a problem, the second `connection.Open()` gets stuck.

```
// connList : connection string List
// query : to execute query
public DataSet SendQueryMultiConnection(List<string> connList, string query)
{
    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        DataSet retDs = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            foreach(string conn in connList)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(conn)) 
                    throw new Exception("No ConnectionData");
                        
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                        {
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                            adapter.Fill(dt);

                            retDs.Tables.Add(dt);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            scope.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //...
        }

        return redDs;
    }
}
```

I can't guess a clue, what is the problem in my code?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I never use Transaction Scope.  I know multiple connection uses a Connection Pool.  The following may explain what is wrong.  The code uses two connections and you have one.  Read all the commends : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thanks  @jdweng  I read you attached link, but i figure out it was my mistake. i sended same sql-server that was problem..

Comment: @M.JiHong what's the point of this code? Distributed transactions are expensive and complex. Do you *really* need to load data from different **servers**? You don't need a different connection to read from different databases n the same server. You can specify the database as in a three-part table name in the query itself

Comment: @CaiusJard No, this problem in working on Winform. I didn't know that EF team dropped support! Thanks!

Comment: @M.JiHong on the other hand, if you work with datasets, you can construct the dataset and adapters in advance. If you use typed datasets you even get a GUI to create the dataset, tables and adapters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have 3 different test databases and i tring to execute a query to update table for distribute transactions. Is that distribute transactions, right? but, i was execute a query to two databases who inside same database engine.. So that the task was stucked haha..

Comment: @M.JiHong unless they're on different **servers** (or instances) you only need a single connection and no distributed transactions. If you check [the ADO.NET docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter#populating-a-dataset-from-multiple-dataadapters) you'll see there's no reason to create the dataset and adapters while running the queries. You can create them in advance and only call them to load the tables in the end

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I thought you were using EF - must have had another tab open with a db context in it..  Also, don't need to make sqlconn and command - can just pass those as string sto sqldataadapter constructor. Adapter knows how to open a conenction too

Comment: @CaiusJard No problem! oh.. EF is convenient! Thanks.